# How to represent a Question/Answer page inside my asp.net MVC core web application

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following 3 models, which represents a submission of questions/answers:-

```
public partial class Submission
    {
        public Submission()
        {
            SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public bool Independent { get; set; }
        public string Comment { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
    }

public partial class SubmissionQuestion
    {
        public SubmissionQuestion()
        {
            SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
    }


public partial class SubmissionQuestionSubmission
    {
        public int SubmissionQuestionId { get; set; }
        public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
        public string Answer { get; set; }

        public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
        public virtual SubmissionQuestion SubmissionQuestion { get; set; }
    }
```

now i want to build a view which will show the submission firstname,lastname & comments + all the questions and for each question to show the answer fields as a free text for the user to enter it. to be honest i am not sure how i need to build the view and receive it inside the action method? any help?

Comment: Did your requirement like:a user login the system to join an exam with specified several questions and the user need to complete the exam with answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to display the data of **specified** submission's `firstname`,`lastname`,`comments`,the related `questions`.And with each `question`,you could enter an `answer`.Then pass the filled data to the action.

Here is a simple demo like below:

Model:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public List<string> Question { get; set; }
    public List<string> Answer { get; set; }
}
public partial class Submission
{
    public Submission()
    {
        SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Independent { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
}

public partial class SubmissionQuestion
{
    public SubmissionQuestion()
    {
        SubmissionQuestionSubmission = new HashSet<SubmissionQuestionSubmission>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubmissionQuestionSubmission> SubmissionQuestionSubmission { get; set; }
}


public partial class SubmissionQuestionSubmission
{
    public int SubmissionQuestionId { get; set; }
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
    public string Answer { get; set; }

    public virtual Submission Submission { get; set; }
    public virtual SubmissionQuestion SubmissionQuestion { get; set; }
}
```

View(If you want to edit the firstname,lastname..you could remove the `readonly`):

```
@model ViewModel
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Comment" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Comment" class="form-control" readonly />
                <span asp-validation-for="Comment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.Question.Count(); i++)
            {
                <label>@Model.Question[i]</label><br />
                <input asp-for="@Model.Question[i]"  hidden />
                <input asp-for="@Model.Answer[i]"  />
                <br />
            }           
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    //specified one submissions' data and the related questions
    var model = await _context.Submission.Include(s => s.SubmissionQuestionSubmission)
        .ThenInclude(s => s.SubmissionQuestion).Select(s => new ViewModel()
        {
            FirstName = s.FirstName,
            LastName = s.LastName,
            Comment = s.Comment,
            Question = s.SubmissionQuestionSubmission.Where(s => s.SubmissionId == 1).Select(s => s.SubmissionQuestion.Question).ToList(),
        }).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(ViewModel submission)
{
    //do your stuff...
    return View();
}
```

Result:
[image]